# How to restric acces for the wordpress website for non-autorized users?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm developing the website and the main idea is having access only for users that I created and give them credentials for access
So I want to add the code in my function.php which will always redirect non-authorized users to the page-login.php and after user secussully logged redirect them to the home page.
Trying to avoid plugins here as I think it's quite simple task, but just can not find the proper example for this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`is_user_logged_in()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/) for this:

```
function redirect_non_logged_in_user() {
    // Get the global $wp object
    global $wp;
    
    // if is_user_logged_in() returns false AND the "request" property does not equal the wp_login_url. Prevents an infinite loop
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && $wp->request !== wp_login_url() ) :
        // redirect to the wp_login_url()
        wp_redirect( wp_login_url(), 302 );
        exit();
    endif;
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_non_logged_in_user');
```

Logged in user redirect to home page:

```
// Runs on the login_redirect hook.
function redirect_logged_in_user() {
    return home_url();
}

add_filter('login_redirect', 'redirect_logged_in_user');
```

Comment: @StanislavShokarev I made some updates, most likely after you copied the code. I tested this and it was working as expected.

Comment: many thanks for your help but I changed code a bit to
wp_redirect( home_url('login'), 302 );

where 'login' is a slug of my page. And still gives me too many redirects when I trying to load the website

Comment: @StanislavShokarev did you also change this line `$wp->request !== home_url('login')`? Also, why are you redirecting your home page to the login page? It should simply be `wp_redirect('/login', 302)` and then `$wp->request !== 'login'`

Comment: ok cool, now when I click on the menu links it goes to pages still. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Are you logged in? I tested on my environment and clicking on any menu item when not logged in, redirects to the login page. If you are logged in, you can get to any page.